# Google Analytcs Data without login

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have an application made with Angular 5 and I want to show some Google Analytcs data on the page.
The problem is that the analytcs reporting API needs authentication and I need to everyone who access application to see it.

Is there a way to make that possible?

Comment: You don't have any kind of backend yet? If you fully trust your users, you could in theory store the API keys in the frontend and query in the frontend, but if you don't, you will need a backend.

Comment: Create your report in data studio and embed it in your page. Or pull them to a Google Spreadsheet via the GA add-on, publish to the web and embed that in your web page.

Comment: Actually I access it by the google analytcs reporting API using the javascript library and I dont have a backend.
To use it requires a login registered on google analytcs plus the API keys and I cant add everyone because will be many aceess
Do you know how can I fix the email to login? I know I will expose the credencials

Comment: Did you resolve this?